# Python ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list error

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner and I wrote a code that the computer takes some numbers as a list and removes compound numbers and keeps prime numbers then prints the list. It doesn't work with numbers greater than 5 and gives
`ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list error.`

```
a=list(map(int,input('Enter some numbers:').split()))
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    b=a[i]
    for j in range(2,b):
        if b%j==0:
            a.remove(b)
        else:
            pass
else:
    print('The prime numbers are:',a)
```

Comment: Modifying a list while iterating over it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that the removal loop:

```
for j in range(2,b):
    if b%j==0:
        a.remove(b)
    else:
        pass
```

will continue running even after the element is removed, so for `b = 6`, it will attempt to remove 6 twice: once for `j = 2` and again for `j = 3`. You can solve it by adding a `break` after the `a.remove` line.

You also don't need an `else` clause if there's nothing to be done there, so the last two lines of the loop can be removed, and you'll also likely have issues with `i` going out of range since you're modifying the list `a` during the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a list while iterating over it is not a good idea.

Instead, create a new list containing the prime numbers.

```
def isprime(x):
  for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(x)) + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
      return False
  return True

a = list(map(int, input('Enter some numbers:').split()))

b = [x for x in a if isprime(x)]
```